# token input not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-tokeninput

I am getting values on variable "url" but my textbox not geting that values when variable assigned to Tokeninput..instead when i pass values directly to tokeninput my textbox is working..Finally i need to read my text box when i pass variable as tokeninput..  Thanks in advance

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       var url;
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "Tokeninput.aspx/GetData",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           data: JSON.stringify({ Locale: 'en-US' }),
           datatype: 'json',
           async: false,
           success: function (data) {
               xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data.d);
               $xml = $(xmlDoc);
               $title = $xml.find("status");
               if ($title.attr("code") == "0") {
                   url = ($title.text());
               }
           },
           error: function (e) {
               alert("check once...");
           }
       });
       alert(url);
       $("#myTextBox").tokenInput([{"name":"Bhai"},{"name":"Bhargavi"},{"name":"Bhargav"},{"name":"Akka"},{"name":"Amma"},{"name":"Anil"},{"name":"Amar"}], {
       //$("#myTextBox").tokenInput(url, {
           theme: "facebook",
           preventDuplicates: true
       });
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to pass a JSON object as the parameter, not a JSON string.

Try this:

```
$("#myTextBox").tokenInput(JSON.Parse(url), {
           theme: "facebook",
           preventDuplicates: true
       });
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you could accept and up vote the answer if it solved your problem, that would be great! Thanks!