# Token-input is not able to access ASP.Net Web Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tokeninput

I am using the [token-input plugin](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) in my ASP.NET project.

I have a web method as shown below,

```
public partial class User : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    [WebMethod]
    public static List<IdAndName> GetDescriptions()
    {
        return DBQueryManager.GetDistinctDescriptions();
    }
```

```js
$('#DescriptionFilterTxtBox').tokenInput("User.aspx/GetDescriptions", {
    hintText: "Key in atleast 2 chars. First 20 match is displayed.",
    searchDelay: 25,                
    minChars: 1,
    resultsLimit: 10,
    tokenValue: name
});
```

I am trying to get the data from the `GetDescriptions` method and display it in the `DescriptionFilterTxtBox` but, it is not working. Basically, the plugin is not able to hit the web method.

How can I hit the ASP.Net Web Method from the tokeninput plugin? Any help/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: the control is not going to GetDescriptions()?

Comment: @Sachu, yes. It is not able to hit webmethod in aspx page.

Comment: i used the plugin on mvc..for aspx most of the ppl suggest create a jason function and use the url refere [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664448/token-input-not-working]

Answer (score 0):

Your method needs the *q* parameter:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<IdAndName> GetDescriptions(string q)
{
    return DBQueryManager.GetDistinctDescriptions();
}
```

> Your script must accept a GET parameter named q which will contain the term to search for. E.g. http://www.example.com/myscript?q=query

[jquery-tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)

You also need to return a JSON from the method.